# How to run WinRT app at start up via task scheduler?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, scheduled-tasks

I want to open my personal WinRT app to open automatically when I start Win 8. I checked task scheduler. It has option for "Start a program". In that what should I pass in field "Program/Script" ?

Answer (score 0):

A WinRT app can register file associations or protocol associations. You can register one and schedule with a command line like this

```
cmd /c start autoexec.myext
```

or

```
cmd /c start myprotocol://autoexec
```

Answer (score 0):

Find another good workaround in the [SuperUser-Forum](https://superuser.com/questions/433477/how-do-i-run-a-metro-application-from-the-command-line-in-windows-8):

Create a new vbs-File:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.SendKeys "^{ESC}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
WScript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Save the file to your autostart or register as startup script.
Open it with: `filename.vbs YourAppName` to open your App by AppName